# How can I remove "/url?q=" from text data in R

Tags: r, url

I want to remove "/url?q=" from text data in R Studio.
This is my code for google search:

```
## Code for Google Search
# Enter Search Term Here
 search.term <- "r-project"
# Creating Function
 getGoogleURL <- function(search.term, domain = '.co.in', quotes=TRUE) 
{
   # Getting Search Term
    search.term <- gsub(' ', '%20', search.term)
    if(quotes) search.term <- paste('%22', search.term, '%22', sep='') 
   # Putting Search Term in Google Search
    getGoogleURL <- paste('http://www.google', domain, '/search?q=', search.term, sep='') }

## Get Links from Google Search
# Creating Function to Get URLs From Search Results
 getGoogleLinks <- function(google.url) {
  # Creating a File to Save URLs
   doc <- getURL(google.url, httpheader = c("User-Agent" = "R(3.4.0)"))
  # Removing HTML code and Setting Nodes
   html <- htmlTreeParse(doc, useInternalNodes = TRUE, error=function(...){})
   nodes <- getNodeSet(html, "//h3[@class='r']//a")
   return(sapply(nodes, function(x) x <- xmlAttrs(x)[["href"]])) }

## Remove quoted text, Create URL List
  quotes <- "FALSE"
  search.url <- getGoogleURL(search.term=search.term, quotes=quotes)
  links <- getGoogleLinks(search.url)

## Print URL List
  links
```

And my result is:

> [1] "/url?q=https://www.r-project.org/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj78ZWXoabUAhUcTI8KHaTEDTIQFggUMAA&usg=AFQjCNEqtiOAIA7OOTa3meWC8zaTjjTy8A"
>   [2] "/url?q=http://www.cran.r-project.org/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj78ZWXoabUAhUcTI8KHaTEDTIQjBAIGzAB&usg=AFQjCNF8QmYbLzG0c66QZM2wsXF1n1-9tQ"

What can I do to remove "/url?q=" from the links above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gsub.

```
## Code for Google Search
# Enter Search Term Here
 search.term <- "r-project"
# Creating Function
 getGoogleURL <- function(search.term, domain = '.co.in', quotes=TRUE) 
{
   # Getting Search Term
    search.term <- gsub(' ', '%20', search.term)
    if(quotes) search.term <- paste('%22', search.term, '%22', sep='') 
   # Putting Search Term in Google Search
    getGoogleURL <- paste('http://www.google', domain, '/search?q=', search.term, sep='') }

## Get Links from Google Search
# Creating Function to Get URLs From Search Results
 getGoogleLinks <- function(google.url) {
  # Creating a File to Save URLs
   doc <- getURL(google.url, httpheader = c("User-Agent" = "R(3.4.0)"))
  # Removing HTML code and Setting Nodes
   html <- htmlTreeParse(doc, useInternalNodes = TRUE, error=function(...){})
   nodes <- getNodeSet(html, "//h3[@class='r']//a")
   return(sapply(nodes, function(x) x <- xmlAttrs(x)[["href"]])) }

## Remove quoted text, Create URL List
  quotes <- "FALSE"
  search.url <- getGoogleURL(search.term=search.term, quotes=quotes)
  links <- getGoogleLinks(search.url)

## Print URL List
  gsub("/url?q=", "", links)
```

Comment: Thanks but I solved my problem using 'substring' instead.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way as they were limited number of characters

```
links <- substring(links,8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to @JTeam's answer you can try this (given the links always start with `/url?q=`):

`lapply(links,function(x) paste0(strsplit(x,'=')[[1]][-1],collapse = ''))`

This gives you a nice list of clean links (if you prefer a vector, try `sapply`)

Comment: Thanks but I solved my problem using 'substring' instead.